# DDL date data type in check constraint manipulation in oracle

Tags: oracle, date, constraints, ddl

i'm creating a table that should check  various date constraint, but oracle is kind ticky on this argument. My goal is to reserve a certain room for let's say a lecture, so i tought of something like this :

....
prenotation_date date NOT NULL,
starting_date    date NOT NULL,
ending_date      date NOT NULL,

check (/*strarting_date > prenotation_date+3gg*/ ) -> you can book a room only 3 days after the time you're asking the reservation

check (/* starting_date = ending_date */ ) in regards of the **date** you're booking, meaning you can book a room for a period of one day

check (/* starting_date < ending_date */) in regards of the **time** you're considering, meaning that the time in witch you start to use the room must be earlier of the time you intend of leaving the room (let's say you want to reserve it from 8:00 a.m. to 10:00 a.m.

the problem is that i don't know how consider just a portion of the data, but i guess there's a way to accomplish that, otherwise you should create 4 columns instead of  2 and use for a couple a dummy date and for the other a dummmy time,  wich seems cluncky to me. So i guess the question is, how do i consider the date type in its single components ? Is that even possible ? thanks for the attention and sorry for the long post.

Comment: A check constraint would suffice. I have provided a complete test case for each condition checked. See my answer.

Comment: The answers here are correct but the logic is prone to error.  What happens when the boss says "Book the room now"?  Are you going to tell them "I have to change the code on the production database?" Consider a separate table with the "these will never change" numbers as values. Then refer to these in the trigger instead of hard coded values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a **CHECK** constraint with following conditions:

1. starting_date > prenotation_date + 3
2. starting_date < ending_date
3. TRUNC(starting_date) = TRUNC(ending_date)

`starting_date > prenotation_date + 3` will make sure that the **booking is allowed after 3 days of the reservation**.

`starting_date < ending_date` will make sure that the **time at which a booking is made is always before to the leaving time**.

`TRUNC(starting_date) = TRUNC(ending_date)` will make sure that the booking is done for the same day. **That is the booking window is only for one single day.**

**Test case:**

**CREATE TABLE**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(
  2  prenotation_date DATE NOT NULL, starting_date DATE NOT NULL, ending_date DATE NOT NULL);

Table created.

SQL>
```

**ADD CHECK CONSTRAINT**

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT t_chk CHECK(
  2  (starting_date > prenotation_date + 3)
  3  AND (starting_date < ending_date)
  4  AND (TRUNC(starting_date) = TRUNC(ending_date))
  5  );

Table altered.

SQL>
```

**INSERT** : check `starting_date > prenotation_date + 3`. Below insert should fail.

```
SQL> INSERT
  2  INTO t VALUES
  3    (
  4      to_date('03/01/2015 00:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
  5      to_date('03/02/2015 08:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
  6      to_date('03/02/2015 10:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  7    );
INSERT
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (LALIT.T_CHK) violated


SQL>
```

**INSERT** : check starting_date < ending_date. Below insert should fail.

```
SQL> INSERT
  2  INTO t VALUES
  3    (
  4      to_date('02/01/2015 00:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
  5      to_date('03/02/2015 10:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
  6      to_date('03/02/2015 08:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  7    );
INSERT
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (LALIT.T_CHK) violated


SQL>
```

**INSERT** : check booking is done for the same day. Below insert should fail. Note the time `08:00:00` and `10:00:00` for start and end time respectively.

```
SQL>   INSERT
  2  INTO t VALUES
  3    (
  4      to_date('02/01/2015 00:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
  5      to_date('03/02/2015 08:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
  6      to_date('04/02/2015 10:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  7    );
  INSERT
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (LALIT.T_CHK) violated


SQL>
```

**INSERT** : All values satisfy the requirement, below insert should pass.

```
SQL> INSERT
  2  INTO t VALUES
  3    (
  4      to_date('02/01/2015 00:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
  5      to_date('03/02/2015 08:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
  6      to_date('03/02/2015 10:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  7    );

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Comment: great observations, thank you very much. Altough i don't understand how TRUNC works. Is the default to truncate the date cutting the time span away? i tough the solution was something with to_date - to_char nested function in order to isolate the parameter of interest; wich by the way, i can't get to work.

Comment: Apparently my idea was logically correct, but awful nontheless. I tought to compare the dates in the string domain to achieve the first check -> to_char(starting_date,'mm/dd/yyyy') = to_char(ending_date,'mm/dd/yyyy')

Comment: Trunc removes the time element from a DATE. So, the truncted value will have a datetime value as DATE+00:00:00 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should just to learn how to work with dates in Oracle and SQL :) There are several ways to do this. For example:

```
-- Check whether room was booked timely
alter table Reservations add constraint RC1
  check (trunc(starting_date, 'DD') >= trunc(prenotation_date, 'DD') + 3);

-- Disable booking ranges around midnight
alter table Reservations add constraint RC2
  check (trunc(starting_date, 'DD') = trunc(ending_date, 'DD'));

-- Check whether booked range exists
alter table Reservations add constraint RC3
  check (starting_date < ending_date);
```